# How to fix the size of a tag "li"?

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

I'm trying to create a menu like [this](http://www.sharedimage.net/pictures/fec675ea20fb3ed45726717fd0647eb1.jpg) or [this](http://www.sharedimage.net/pictures/09b10ca63c3c8cd4000aaa24a104e5e2.jpg).

But I am trying all ways to fix the size of the tag "read" but I can not.
I'm in the beginning, [to see](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/5jJg3/) where I am.
Notice that when the user hovers the tag "a" changes the background color.

Please, if you can change the code and show me how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you've specified display:inline; and styled it from that point, you'll have to remove that, or change to inline-block like they said, and re-style your menu.

Answer (score 3):

Use `display:inline-block;` instead of inline.

Comment: That's right, we're almost there.
So missing a few details.
1. the text is not centralozado center (both horizontally and vertically)
2. the tag "a" must occupy the whole "read" so that if the user moves the mouse on li he identifies the link and change the background color.  See the link: http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/5jJg3/

Answer (score 1):

You cant declare width  for an inline li , use

```
display:inline-block;
```

Comment: That's right, we're almost there.
So missing a few details.
1. the text is not centralozado center (both horizontally and vertically)
2. the tag "a" must occupy the whole "read" so that if the user moves the mouse on li he identifies the link and change the background color.  See the link: http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/5jJg3/